# PHP, grabbing a MySQL query from a MySQL populated drop down list

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quick disclaimer- This is a homework assignment and I've gone through my notes and book and several online examples but I'm not getting anywhere.

I have database that I need to move into a PHP page. The PHP page will have a drop down list populated by a MySQL query, when the user clicks on a choice the page should return to itself another MySQL query. So when I chose a name, the flight information about that Name should be returned. I know I have to do something with `$_POST` but as having 3 days experience with PHP I'm not really sure how this will work.

```
<?php

try
{       //database login
    $dsn="mysql:host=courses; dbname=z1756942";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    //sql command to populate  drop down list
    $sql = ("SELECT CONCAT(fname,' ', lname) as full_name FROM passenger;");

    //sql statement to return on drop down pick
    $r->full_name;
    $row=$pdo->query($sql);
?>
<!-- start the drop down box -->
<form action=" " method ="POST">
    Passenger by Name:
    <select id="name" name="name">
    <option value= 0>Choose</option>

<?php
    //populate the drop down box
    foreach($row as $r)
    {
    $name=$r['full_name'];
     echo "<option value=\"$name\">".$name.'</option>';
    }
?>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php
```

I have the tags for HTML, body and my catch statement, those all work correctly. The MySQL statement that needs to be returned to the same page is

```
SELECT flightnum, dateofflight, seatnum FROM manifest, passenger WHERE manifest.passnum LIKE passenger.passnum;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I assume you'll want to use this name in your SQL query to lookup the flight information? I've included this in my answer, but I suggest you edit the question to reflect that for others reading your question later ;)

Answer (score 1):

When the user clicks the submit button the selected value will populate in `$_POST['name']`. This is because the `method` you set in your `form` is `POST` and the `name` assigned to the `select` input field in your form is `name`. See the manual page for [Handling external variables](http://php.net/language.variables.external) for more details about dealing with form input in PHP.

So in your example above you can determine whether or not the user has submitted the `name` value by checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. A normal HTTP `GET` request should just load the page and `POST` request triggers the new query.

### Example

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { // user submitted the form
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) { // user submitted a name
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT flightnum, dateofflight, seatnum
                                      FROM manifest, passenger
                                      WHERE manifest.passnum LIKE passenger.passnum
                                          AND passenger.fname = ?
                                          AND passenger.lname = ?'
        );
        // look up the flight info by passenger name
        $name = explode(" ", $_POST['name']);
        if ($stmt->execute($name)) { // statement executed successfully
            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); // rows fetched here
            /* Do whatever with rows */
            echo "Got it!";
        } else { // statement failed for some reason...
            echo "Error executing query!"; // debug with PDO::errorInfo()
            exit; // you should handle this gracefully later
        }
    } else { // user did not submit a name
        echo "Please go back and select a name!";
        exit; // handle graceful failures here
    }
} else { // user just loaded the page
    /* spit out the form here */
}
```